# Why use confidence interval for survival estimates?

Tags: confidence-interval, survival, standard-deviation

I noticed that in most cases people use point estimate + 95%CI to describe survival estimates like the 3-year survival probability.
Mean +/- SD is also a popular method to describe data, why do I see it's rarely used in survival analysis? (Please correct me if I am wrong).
What's the advantage of CI over SD in survival analysis?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's less helpful to report the point estimate $\pm$ standard error than to report the point estimate and a confidence interval.  The reason is that a confidence interval has an *explicit specification of a confidence level* so the reader can judge how likely the confidence interval is to contain the estimated quantity of interest.  If you just report the size of the standard error, it is harder for the reader to judge.  (Also, there is some ambiguity in wording in your question relating to the use of standard deviation versus standard error of an estimator.)